# WSL2 (Ubuntu) sudo snap install --classic code not working

Tags: snap, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code, hostapd

I already had vscode installed 2 years ago, but I opened my wsl2 today after like 10 days and code . is giving following error (It was working fine till 10 days ago)

```
Command 'code' not found, did you mean:

  command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.1build1)
  command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
  command 'node' from deb nodejs (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1)
  command 'ode' from deb plotutils (2.6-10build1)
  command 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

So I thought to reinstall VScode. However when I typed `sudo snap install --classic code` it is showing `error: access denied (see 'snap help login')`

`systemctl status snapd.service` is returning the following:-

```
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-07-18 12:21:18 IST; 10min ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 689 (snapd)
      Tasks: 18 (limit: 7474)
     Memory: 44.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─689 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
```

(Yes systemctl does not work by default in WSL2, but I found a way to enable it)

`snap version` is returning the following

```
snap    2.48+20.04
snapd   2.48+20.04
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

`sudo snap refresh snapd` isn't working too. Giving the same error as of `snap install`

Please help!

Comment: If you've had VSCode working for two years, then you *likely* installed it in Windows, rather than in Ubuntu originally.  That's the normal method for using VSCode with Ubuntu/WSL.  Can you execute `code .` from PowerShell?  If so, then the problem is likely something preventing the Windows path propagating to the Ubuntu `$PATH`.  Would you edit/update your question with the results of running `code .` from PowerShell, along with `echo $PATH` from Ubuntu?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, *"systemctl does not work by default in WSL2, but I found a way to enable it"* -- This *could* very well be the problem itself.  Running Systemd in WSL overwrites the normal WSL path functionality unless you take special care to preserve it.  Please include the "way" you enabled it, since that's likely going to be important.  Thanks!